# Speed Optimization in Django

Tags: python, django, optimization, query-optimization

I am building a Blog App and I am also thinking to implement video posts in it. I am trying to optimize the speed of the Web App in Development and also in Production.

I have deployed many sites build in Django in last several months on [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/). I've noticed that most of site contains simple functionalities like :- `Create`, `Edit`, `Image Upload`, `ListView`, `DetailView` of Blogs , etc. With `500 to 600 lines of Code (python)`. BUT they are very slow even with 2 to 5 pages.

**Talking about Development :-**

When i open a page that contains 100 to 150 Blogs with Images, then it is taking 2 to 3 seconds to open the page AND then i think this may be Because of more blogs and queries then I checked the page's queries and query's Time using [Django-Debug-Toolbar](https://pypi.org/project/django-debug-toolbar/) then I deleted all the posts except 1 post after that I saw in `debug-toolbar`, it is showing

- `Total time to load the Page is`  *600ms*.
- *4 queries* in *6 to 8ms*

I removed some queries but still same results.

I also searched about it then i found a Post of optimizing queries using **select_related** then I also used it BUT I didn't see any much improvement.

I used to make more and more `for loops` as a beginner in `Template` but then I read somewhere (sorry but I don't remember the source) **"Use logical functionalities like `for loop`, `if else`, etc in `views`  instead of `templates`"**.

**Talking about Production :-**

In my site in production -  Logging In , Creating or Uploading File , Loading image in site seems pretty slow in site. So I think that may be because of the Database I am using , So I contacted them to ask if database slows down the site speed (performance) then they said :-

> The speed of your site is very much dependent on the speed of the code that you have written to handle the requests that come in. The specific database probably will not have an effect on the speed of image downloading, but the fact that you're not using the static files system will.

BUT I just wrote code like anyone would do for show the lists of Blog Posts and I am using `MEDIA ROOT` and `STATIC files` after that images are still loading slowly.

AND I also worked according to [Django-Documentation-About-Performance and Optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/performance/#work-at-the-appropriate-level) like :- using `counting objects using .count() will increase the speed`.

After that I still didn't find any prefect solution for optimizing the site in `Production` and `Development`.

**The Blog Web App's views and models that i am working on and trying to optimize the site**

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='',validators=[validate_is_profane])
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_posts',blank=True,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
```

views.py

```
def posts(request):
    blog_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user_id=request.user)
    now = timezone.now()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(date__lte=now).order_by('-date').exclude(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_blog_post = BlogPostForm(request.POST,
                                    request.FILES,
                                    instance=request.user.profile)

        if which_post_form.is_valid():
            new_blog_post = new_blog_post.save(commit=False)
            new_blog_post.save()
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        new_blog_post = BlogPostForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'posts':posts,
        'blog_profile':blog_profile,
        'new_blog_post':new_blog_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'post_list.html', context)
```

post_list.html

```
{% for topic in posts %}

<br>


<a href="{% url 'user_profile' user.id %}">{{ topic.user }}</a>

<p>{{ topic.title|truncatechars:10 }}</p>

{% if topic.image %}
<br>
<a><img src="{{ topic.image.url }}" id="myImg" width="300"></a>
<br>
{% endif %}


<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>



<a>{{ topic.description|slice:":10" }}</a>

<a href="{{ topic.get_absolute_url }}">More</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

If you have any further solution about , How you optimized your site . then I will really appreciate you Answers and suggestions.

Comment: If you're making 4 queries to display one item that probably does indicate you're making a large number of queries that will perform badly when displaying many objects (where any given query is fast but making many is still slow), but you need to compare that with the queries that are made when you have many objects- it could still be 4 if you're using `select_related` well, or it could be `4 * num_objects` if you're not querying efficiently. If you need additional help, you'll also need to provide samples of what your code (view and model) looks like.

Comment: @tari, Thanks for your Suggestion. I have uploaded the `models.py` and `views.py`. BUT i provided code of only of Blog App i am working on, BUT in question i am also talking about my other sites which contains simple `creating` and `editing` functionalities  even they are slow with few functionalities ( With 2 to 3 page sites ). AND i think i didn't do any `conditional functions` in them BUT they are still very slow

Comment: Can you also share a template? There's nothing obviously inefficient in the code you've shared so far.

Comment: That's what i am saying that even with simple functionalities, sites are very slow

Comment: @tari, I have updated the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things that could cause bad performance if you have a lot of data, where the first is more likely to be a problem:

Accesses to `topic.user` in the template will make an extra query for every item in `posts` by default, since that attribute access needs to load information for the `User` model from a different table. Doing a `select_related('user')` when getting your `Post` queryset will load user information in the same query as posts:

```py
Post.objects.filter(date__lte=now) \
    .order_by('-date') \
    .exclude(user=request.user) \
    .select_related('user')
```

I strongly suspect avoiding a query per post this way will solve your performance issues, since if a typical query takes around 10ms and you need to make hundreds of them, that could easily blow your response time out to multiple seconds. Since you're not actually reading a lot of data, the time a query takes will be dominated by fixed overheads that you can avoid by simply doing fewer queries.

---

While it's less likely to be a problem unless you have a large number of posts (tens of thousands or more), ordering your `Post`s by `date` will require the database to read every row of the table and sort them before returning any rows. With a few hundred objects this has negligible cost, but with many thousands it would be slower.

If you [add an index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/indexes/) over the fields you query and sort by you can help the database do things efficiently:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-date'], name='date_ordering'),
        ]
```

Comment: I understand everything you said BUT how will i access posts by `date` using **Index** method ?

Comment: No differently: that changes the database schema to tell it to maintain an index, and it chooses to use indexes on its own.